# What's the best way to trim() all elements in a List<String>?

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a `List<String>`, potentially holding thousands of strings.  I am implementing a validation method, which includes ensuring that there aren't any leading or trailing whitespaces in each string.

I'm currently iterating over the list, calling [String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) for each `String`, and adding it to a new `List<String>` and reassigning back to the original list after:

```
List<String> trimmedStrings = new ArrayList<String)();
for(String s : originalStrings) {
  trimmedStrings.add(s.trim());
}

originalStrings = trimmedStrings;
```

I feel like there's a [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way to do this.  Are there alternate, more efficient approaches here? Thanks!

Edit:  Yes I am on Java 8, so Java 8 suggestions are welcome!

Comment: The linked question talks about uppercasing each String but this is the same here for trimming: `originalStrings.replaceAll(String::trim);`

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Strings are immutable, which means you have to work with new String objects than the one already in the List. With specific List implementations you could remove an element and insert the trimmed object at the same position, that would save you the second ``List``.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Java 8, you should use something like:

```
List<String> trimmedStrings = 
    originalStrings.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

also it is possible to use unary `String::trim` operator for elements of the initial list (untrimmed `String` instances will be overwritten) by calling this method:

```
originalStrings.replaceAll(String::trim);
```

Comment: Thanks Cootri.  How does your solution differ from Tunaki's `originalStrings.replaceAll(String::trim)`?

Comment: he modifies elements of the input list. So there is no need to declare new `trimmedStrings` list and waste more space. But the initial untrimmed `String` values will be lost

Comment: You should suggest a Java 7 solution, here is one I put together: http://pastebin.com/sF3ixCq4

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Why? This question is tagged Java 8. There is no need to add more code for the fun of it. Especially that it introduces classes that do not exist like `CollectionUtil`.

Comment: @Tunaki: I simply added a suggestion. I only added the missing class... :(

Comment: why does not foreach work ? for example, `list.foreach(str->  str = str.trim())`

Comment: I was working something more complex and your code helped Cootri. Thanks you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on java-8, you can use :

```
    final List<Object> result = arrayList.stream()
        .map(String::trim)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```